# FQL applying additional filters

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-page

At the bottom of the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page) for the FQL 'page' table it says

> Note: Additional filters on other columns can be specified but they may make the query less efficient.

I want to filter by page type but if I attempt the query

```
SELECT name FROM page WHERE type = 'Musician/band'

  "error": {
    "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
```

Is there anyway to filter by page type?

Update:

My Graph Search beta just kicked in on my account and I can now do this through my browser and facebook account with the url:

http://www.facebook.com/search/musician/pages/114952118516947/home-residents/pages-liked/intersect

Is there a way to get this data in JSON or XML?

Comment: Seeing your query I would suggest you to try [Graph Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search) instead of FQL

Comment: The current graph search API with type=page searches for Facebook pages of all types, there is no call filter for page type.

Comment: Yeah, the data might not be 100% correct always but as for your query I tried [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3DMusician%2Fband%26type%3Dpage) and got pages, mostly of them had page type "Musician/band".

Comment: True Anvesh but now you've used up the search term and API searches are limited to 500 results including pagination so you can't get much data that way.

Comment: @BenPearce, were you able to find solution? thanks.